# What settings are required for Windows IOT Core HDMI to TVs/Monitors

Tags: hdmi, windows-iot

I've reset my Win 10 RaPi a few times and each time I've come unstuck on the settings that I need to reapply to get my HD Samsung TV working again.

What settings are required for particular TV's?

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by adding my particular configuration;

**Samsung 24" HD [T24C300EW](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00CP3O6YQ/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=B00CP3O6YQ&linkCode=as2&tag=liqui-21)**

```
HDMI_GROUP=1 # This means CEA and refers to TV's not monitors
#HDMI_MODE=1 # This is not used or required and gives 1080P resolution
```

Please add other config

Comment: Hopefully this can grow in a good wiki